# how to change the text of qlineedit when Qlistview index is changed in another qdialog?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt4

Hi i want get the text string of QListView in my main window when i click a button in Qdialog. my implementation is :

[image]

in Qdialog

```
void hist::getValue(){
    QModelIndexList templatelist =
        ui->listView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
    QStringList stringlist;
    foreach (const QModelIndex &index, templatelist) {
      stringlist.append(index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
    }
    qDebug()<<stringlist;
    // return stringlist;   // what i need to here to return stringlist ?
}

void hist::on_downloadselected_clicked() {

    connect(ui->downloadselected, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(accept()));

    // TODO selected download
}
```

in mainwindow

```
void mainwindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    hist history;
    history.exec();
    if( history.exec() == QDialog::Accepted ){
       QString damn = history.getValue();  // am getting error here 
       ui->url->setText(damn);
       qDebug()<<"pressed";
    }
}
```

Comment: Update the proto `void hist::getValue()` to return a `Qstring` as you expect in mainwindow or `QStringList` if you need all value from the Qlist (in mainwindow & qdialog).

Comment: @Megasa3 what argument ??

Comment: @Megasa3 i want get the text of selected listitem in  my mainwindow when a button is clicked from dialog conatiniing that Qlistview.

Comment: "am getting error here", it's usually good idea to tell what error. Though it's clear here, your method is returning `void`, ie nothing. If there are multiple items selected, what do you want to do? Perhaps you should prevent multiple items from being selected (by setting appropriate properties of the list widget)? Then just make `getValue` to return the first (and hopefully only) selection as a QString.

Comment: i soved that last night will put my solution here

Answer (score 0):

Your compilation error is of course because your method returned `void`, and you tried to use its return value anyway. You probably want something like this, untested code:

```
// changed to return first selection, or empty QString if no selection
QString hist::getValue(){
    QModelIndexList templatelist =
        ui->listView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
    if (templatelist.isEmpty()) 
        return QString(); // empty string
    else 
        return templatelist.first().data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString();t ?
}

void hist::on_downloadselected_clicked() {
    // why did you even have connect here?
    if (!getValue().isEmpty())
        accept(); // close the dialog with accept if selection made
    else
        reject(); // or do nothing?
}
```

Comment: i solved my problem  last night , well thanks for code i did something like above :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem with the folowing codes in particular file 
in mainwindow

```
void mainwindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
hist history;
// history.exec();
if( history.exec() == QDialog::Accepted){
ui->url->setText(history.inputstring());
on_downloadButton_clicked();
}
else if( history.close() == QDialog::Rejected ) {
    history.close();
}
}
```

In dialog

```
QString hist::inputstring() {

QModelIndexList templatelist =
ui->listView->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
QString  stringlist;
foreach (const QModelIndex &index, templatelist) {
stringlist.append(index.data(Qt::DisplayRole).toString());
}
return stringlist;
}
```